# $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{{n+1}}}{{{n}}}{a_n} $ is absolutely convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

prove that if  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n} $ is absolutely convergent $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{{n+1}}}{{{n}}}{a_n} $ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Hmmm... Attempts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this inequality

$$\frac{n+1}n |a_n|\le 2|a_n|$$

Comment: Nice and simple.